# cfquery: Could not find prepared statement with handle x

Tags: coldfusion

We are receiving the following error intermittently, but often:

`Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Could not find prepared statement with handle 1.`

I implemented the two solutions to this problem that I was able to find-

1. Put a semicolon at the end of the query (supposedly to force recompile of query)
2. Put this MS-SQL at the end of the query:  `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

I applied fix 1 and the errors stopped for the remainder of that day.  The following day the error was back.

I applied fix 2 and the same thing happened- no more errors until the following day.

I do understand that whenever I use a `<cfqueryparam>` a prepared statement is used automatically, but isn't there a way to force the db to "re-prepare" every time the query is used and not rely on cached statements?

Note that I do not have admin access to this Cf server.

Cf version is 9.0.0

SQL Server 9.0.3054.

The offending query:

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#" name="q" maxrows="1">
SELECT
ID
FROM
tableOne
WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.ID#">
ORDER BY ID
</cfquery>
```

Thanks

Comment: check your http logs and see if there was a value for url.id.  Or, set url.id to an empty string and try the query.  See if you get the same error message.

Comment: Dan- in the logs, url.ID was set to an integer in all cases.  Running the query with an value="" yielded `Invalid data '' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER`.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is the actual SQL statement really `SELECT ID  FROM ...` or does it use `SELECT * FROM ...`. If it is the latter, for grins try specifying a column list, instead of `*`.

Comment: Leigh, the actual query in production specifies a column list.

Comment: Okay. Honestly I do not know exactly what causes the issue, but if it is a server or dsn configuration issue like it sounds, you will need to get the server admin involved to resolve it.

Comment: **Update**  See [_this_](http://www.mail-archive.com/cf-talk@houseoffusion.com/msg279978.html), which is old but seems relevant.  The "Could not find..." error went away when they changed to jTDS driver (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CachedWithin attribute to your cfquery statement..

```
<cfquery 
    name="GetParks" datasource="#dsn#" name="q" maxrows="1" 
    cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)#">
```

the above example will keep the query out of the cache at all times

Comment: i don't think you can use this solution with cfqueryparam in versions 8 or previous

Comment: (Edit) No, that is a totally different type of caching. It refers to how long the [query *results* are stored in CF memory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-746f.html#WSFD7C6646-3A9E-4088-9667-EC00D5AE041D). It does not relate to [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Whether or not it makes sense, the `cachedwithin` fix has reduced occurrences of the error by 90% or so, which is an acceptable level.  Thanks to all.

Comment: @Leigh the isolation was in coldfusion 8 and previous versions. maybe 9.0.0 actually I never tested it. Pure speculation on the core, but I think it's because the cache mechanisms across all query handling have been "synced" into a single object. It's actually more annoying than anything really, this solution basically exploits one bug to solve another bug. 

@ blippoids you may want to play with the time variables in the CreateTimeSpan(),you might be able to reduce that error rate even more.

Comment: @XaxD - Honestly I do not know enough about the internals to feel much confidence in these kind of assumptions one way or the other... :) As far as theories go, they are not totally off the wall, but relying on unproven/unpredictable side affects (that have side effects of their own) does not sit well. Personally, I would still be looking for the root cause and a solid fix. *Re: play with the time variables in the CreateTimeSpan()* Just keep in mind that means the query may not be retrieving the latest data. If the underlying table changes frequently, that may be an issue.

Comment: @Leigh may is an understatement. it will be quite taxing on the load and also relay back unpredictable results... but... that error rate though! haha <3

Answer (score 1):

in regards to your error: I've seen that error before when the value of #dsn# changed from one request to the next.
If that is not the case, try applying your CF updates since you're still on 9.0.0.

In regards to your question: Set "Max Pooled Statements" to 0.  This will require CF to re-prepare the statement each time.  Also, unchecking "Maintain Connections" will also require re-compilation since the connection to the DB is re-negotiated on each request.

Also a technical note, SQL Server will always cache the execution plan regardless of what you do in CF.  CF is just holding on to a handle for that prepared statement so it doesn't have to pass the SQL across the wire every time.

Comment: Brad, thanks for the input; I did check and established that #dsn# does not change.  Unfortunately, I cannot change settings on the server or apply updates (the reason for that is non-technical).

Answer (score 0):

this might sound stupid, but have you considered that maybe the maxrows attribute might be causing your pain. Trying using TOP and see what happens.

```
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#" name="q">
SELECT TOP 1
ID
FROM
tableOne
WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.ID#">
ORDER BY ID
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Rob, I gave this a shot and it didn't reduce the occurrence of the error.  It was definitely worth the try (I've seen stranger things throw errors)  Thanks